# Favourite Course in Student Course Table Query

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables:

```
Student(StudentID, StudentName)
Course(CourseID, CourseName)
StudentCourse(StudentID, CourseID) -- junction table to assign courses to students
```

How would I query to get the favourite course--"the course which has highest number of students enrolled"?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fc66/1)

Comment: btw - not everyone can view all sites at any given time, hence its better to post your code here - than somewhere else, it also means in the future people can read your entire question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES COURSEID 
FROM   STUDENTCOURSE 
GROUP  BY COURSEID 
ORDER  BY Count(*) DESC
```

Comment: what if there are courses that have the same highest number? eg Math = 2, Science = 2, English = 2. Only one record will show because of `TOP 1`

Comment: TOP 1 will return only one, what if I have two courses that are favourite, see fiddle

Comment: @Gidil Thanks a lot, I would be glad if I can know more about TOP with TIES

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR: Join me [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18036/top-with-ties)

Answer (score 6):

Try it by using `TOP...WITH TIES`

```
SELECT  TOP 1 WITH TIES c.CourseName,
        COUNT(c.CourseID) totalCount
FROM    student a
        INNER JOIN studentcourse b
            ON a.studentID = b.studentID
        INNER JOIN course c
            ON b.courseID = c.courseID
GROUP BY c.CourseName
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
```

`WITH TIES` show the records that have the same highest number of counts.

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fc66/6)

Comment: didn't know about `WITH TIES` + 1